# sort algorithm compiler error with dynamic array

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm having difficulty getting std::begin() to work with a dynamically allocated array (pointer), where it seems to work fine with a stack-allocated one.

This works:

```
int numbers[100];

// Fill array with numbers

std::sort(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
```

This doesn't

```
int* numbers = new int[10000000];

// Fill array with numbers

std::sort(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
```

Here's the resulting error.

```
ptests.cpp:120:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’
     std::sort(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
                                 ^
ptests.cpp:120:33: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:74:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:60,
                 from ptests.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/initializer_list:89:5: note: template<class _Tp> constexpr const _Tp* std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Tp>)
     begin(initializer_list<_Tp> __ils) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/initializer_list:89:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ptests.cpp:120:33: note:   mismatched types ‘std::initializer_list<_Tp>’ and ‘int*’
     std::sort(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
                                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:51:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/random:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:65,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62,
                 from ptests.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note: template<class _Container> decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&)
     begin(_Container& __cont) -> decltype(__cont.begin())
```

Would it be possible to cast the dynamic pointer to the type begin() expects? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Include the text of your error In your Question. I have no idea what a `.webp` file is. See [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::end(numbers)
```

This `numbers` variable is an

```
int *
```

That's what it's type is. And there's nothing about this pointer to an integer that tells anyone about how many `int`s it's pointing to. You allocated it to point to 10000000 `int`s. But once you've allocated it, all you end up with is a pointer to an `int`, and nothing more. It is up to your code to keep track of what exactly this pointer is pointing you. You'll wind up exactly with the same pointer if you were to write, simply:

```
int n;

int *numbers=&n;
```

This `numbers` pointer is completely identical to the one you've created. It's just a pointer to an `int`. Nothing more, nothing less.

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` do not work for ordinary pointers, like your pointer to an `int` here, because, as I've just said, there's nothing about a pointer to some object that indicates how many consecutive objects it's pointing to. It could be one `int`. It could be two `int`s. Maybe a million. Or maybe nothing it all, if the pointer is a `nullptr`.

If you want to sort your dynamically-allocated `int` array, just pass the beginning and the ending pointer directly:

```
std::sort(number, numbers+10000000);
```