# Can I use std::sort on heap allocated raw arrays?

Tags: c++, sorting, memory-management, heap-memory, dynamic-arrays

We know that when using a contiguous block of memory we can easily get an iterator (here `&arra[0]` or `arra`) and pass the iterators to std::sort.

for instance:

```cpp
int arra[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        arra[i] = rand() % 32000;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)std::cout << arra[i]<<" ";
    std::sort(arra,arra+100);
```

Now if I have a heap allocated array, say, like `arr` here:

```cpp
int len;
    len = 100;
    int* arr = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 32000;
    }
```

I don't know whether I can get an iterator for this array, so can I use std::sort for this array at all?
if not, are there any workarounds to using std::sort on such an array?

Comment: Did you not try it?

Comment: not an exact dupe but has the answer, trying to find a better match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123882/sort-algorithm-compiler-error-with-dynamic-array

Comment: `std::sort(arr, arr + len);` IMHO, it doesn't make any difference for `std::sort()` whether begin and end are addresses to stack or heap. It's just the contiguous storage which is important in this case.

Comment: Some related information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719607/is-the-memory-allocated-by-new-operated-consecutive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointers do meet criteria of [`RandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) which is required by [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). It doesn't matter if they point to stack memory or heap memory, as long as they point to the same (contiguous) array. So you can simply use:

```
std::sort(arr, arr + len);
```

This being said, `std::vector` is probably a better choice for allocating an array on the heap. It will save you the headache of managing memory on your own.

Comment: Does arr+len point to the end of the array even in heap allocation? I was under the impression that once you use heap allocation the memory is no longer a contiguous block, yikes. My bad. :P

Comment: I got confused with the linked list structure. Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Don't worry, everyone has started there :) Yes, array is always contiguous, no matter if you allocate it on the heap or on stack. It's guaranteed by the standard. There are many things that use this property, e.g. operator `[]` is in fact nothing more than pointer addition, so `array[5]` is exactly the same instruction as `*(array + 5)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `std::sort` in the same way in both cases, `std::sort` does not know or care how the memory was allocated.

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ Library, Iterators are basically Fancy Pointers. As such, it is standard-compliant to just increment the pointer to the end of the array to get the "end" pointer:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int len;
    len = 100;
    int* arr = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 32000;
    }
    //Valid, Defined Behavior that works as expected
    std::sort(arr, arr + len);
    //alternative, to make the code easier to read:
    //auto begin = arr;
    //auto end = arr + len;
    //std::sort(begin, end);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

However, some Compilers (like Visual Studio's compiler) recognize that this kind of code is inherently unsafe, because you're required to manually supply the length of the array. As a result, they will cause a (suppressible with a Compiler flag, if you need to) Compile-time error if you try to do this, and advise you use a compiler-provided utility instead:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int len;
    len = 100;
    int* arr = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 32000;
    }

    //MSVC Specific Code!
    auto begin = stdext::make_checked_array_iterator(arr, len);
    auto end = arr + len;
    std::sort(begin, end);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

For more on this particular quick of the Visual Studio compiler, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/checked-iterators?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use std::sort on heap allocated raw arrays?

Yes.

> I don't know whether I can get an iterator for this array

You can.

A pointer to element is a random access iterator for arrays. In the case of an automatic array, the array name implicitly decays into a pointer that you can use as an iterator to beginning of the array. In the case of a dynamic array, the result of `new[]` is already a pointer i.e. an iterator to the beginning of the array. You can get the pointer to the end using pointer arithmetic just like in your example.

The only significant difference between an array variable, and a pointer to a dynamic array regarding the use of `std::sort` is that you cannot use `std::end` or `std::size` with a pointer like you could with an array variable. Instead, you need to separately know the size of the array. In this case you've stored the length in the variable `len`.